# Unable to update DOM on iOS 5 without loosing content on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, ios5, overflow

I am currently working on an iOS webapp and have run into an odd issue. I use -webkit-overflow-scrolling:  touch; to make a scrollable DIV which works great however when I update the DOM in combination with a scrollup effect in CSS the content is no longer viewable when scrolling down. It 'knows' the height of the content as scrolling is unaffected however nothing below the current view is actually viewable and seems to be cut off. Does this make any sense? If so, any ideas as to what might be going on?

Here is the 'scrollup' effect:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideup {
     from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
}
 to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
}
}.favup {
     -webkit-animation-name: slideup;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 350ms;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

This is the CSS for the content DIV which is where everything is being modified at:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow:  auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:  touch;
}
```

Lastly this is the trigger that ends up breaking everything basically:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "<div id=\"fav\" class=\"favup\"></div>";
```

I also update the height after every DOM update to keep the scrolling working properly as talked about here: [iOS div momentum scrolling without fixed height (content loaded via ajax)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844592/ios-div-momentum-scrolling-without-fixed-height-content-loaded-via-ajax/9184324#9184324)

Comment: Hopefully, all of this makes sense if not please feel free to ask for clarification and thank you in advance!

Comment: If I change -webkit-animation-name: slideup; to -webkit-animation-name: none; the error no longer occurs and everything works fine. This must be something related to the transform just not sure what and how to fix.